# Does this wire covering contain asbestos?

Tags: wire, asbestos

I am wondering if anyone (who actually knows) can say whether this wire is likely to contain asbestos.

Thank you in advance!

Jack

[image]

Comment: Is that a multi-layered covering with varying materials over the wire? If so, please post a picture where it’s frayed pulled back so we can see the underlying materials.

Comment: Where did you find this wire at?

Comment: The only way to "actually know" is to have it laboratory tested. It's not obvious to the naked eye, and is actually rather tedious in a lab, per a brief foray into "what that entails." Could just be high temp braided fiberglass insulation. What, and particularly "what age" it's found in might be helpful in either ruling it out or leaving it as a possiblity.

Comment: Hold it in a flame for a couple minutes; asbestos will not burn, about everything else will burn. Fiberglas will melt . There are a few other fibers that will not burn like thorium oxide but chances are slim and none that you have these, unless you got the wire from NASA.

Comment: Looking at the apparent age and details of the metal framework (e.g. slotted screw, apparent patina, etc.) I'd go out on a limb and assume that it is asbestos. Are you looking to replace the wires or what?

Comment: Cloth braid itself did not usually contain asbestos but a layer under the cloth may. The problem with asbestos is it is a fiber and most versions were brittle so the only way to know for sure is to test.

Comment: I agree, the only "for sure" method is testing. Anything that can be done by photo is at best an "educated guess". What's the reason for your concern? Two wires, enclosed in a lamp and not disturbed, is not a serious risk to anyone's health.